# Why did my function didnt get called after i onPress with propTypes

Tags: react-native

I have a problem when I call my `Register` function. It looks like the function is never called. Although, I already call my function, it doesn't show up Register function.

**Register Component:**

```
<TouchableOpacity style={styles.loginButtonStyle} onPress={this.props.onRegisterPress}>
                <Text style={styles.loginButtonTextStyle}>Register</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
RegisterComponent.propTypes = {
    handleFirstChange : PropTypes.func,
    handleLastChange : PropTypes.func,
    handleEmailChange : PropTypes.func,
    handleGenderChange: PropTypes.func,
    handlePasswordChange : PropTypes.func,
    showPassword: PropTypes.func,
    onRegisterPress: PropTypes.func,
    showPassword: PropTypes.bool,
    first_name: PropTypes.string,
    last_name: PropTypes.string,
    email: PropTypes.string,
    gender: PropTypes.string,
    password: PropTypes.string, 
};
```

**RegisterContainer.js:**

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            post : [],
            first_name : '',
            last_name : '' ,
            email : ' ',
            gender : ' ',
            password : ' ',

            showPassword: true,
        }
        this.onRegisterPress = this.onRegisterPress.bind(this);
    }

onRegisterPress() {
        const {post} = this.state;
        if((!this.state.email.trim()) || (!this.state.first_name.trim()) || (!this.state.last_name.trim()) || (!this.state.gender.trim())) {
            Alert.alert("Data tidak boleh kosong");
            return;
        }

        if(!this.state.password.trim()) {
            Alert.alert("Masukan Password");
            return;
        } else {
            this.sendDataDiri();
    }
}

render() {
        return (
            <RegisterComponent
                handleFirstChange = {this.handleFirstChange}
                handleLastChange = {this.handleLastChange}
                handleEmailChange = {this.handleEmailChange}
                handleGenderChange = {this.handleGenderChange}
                handlePasswordChange = {this.handlePasswordChange}
                showPassword={this.showPassword}
                onRegisterPress={this.onRegisterPress}
                showPassword={this.state.showPassword}
                first_name={this.state.first_name}
                last_name={this.state.last_name}
                email={this.state.email}
                gender={this.state.gender}
                password={this.state.password} 
            />
        );
    }
```

**RootNavigation:**

```
import { StackNavigator, TabNavigator, NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation';
import LoginContainer from '../containers/LoginContainer';
import DashboardContainer from '../containers/DashboardContainer';
import NotificationContainer from '../containers/NotificationContainer';
import TransactionComp from '../component/TransactionComp/index'
import RegisterComponent from '../component/RegisterComponent'
import RegisterContainer from '../containers/RegisterContainer'
const AppNavigator = StackNavigator(
    {
        Logout : { screen : LoginContainer },
        Login: { screen: LoginContainer },
        Dashboard: { screen: DashboardContainer },
        Notification: { screen: NotificationContainer },
        Transaction : { screen: TransactionComp },
        Register : { screen : RegisterComponent },
        Back : { screen : LoginContainer },
        RegisterCont : {screen : RegisterContainer }
    },
);


export default AppNavigator;
```

I expect register success after form is filled , but when i click on register button , and nothing happened. what is wrong with my function ?

Comment: Did you try consoling the props received for the RegisterComponent.Is it receiving the function or not?

Comment: nah i already console it but return null . i dont know. did i call wrong in function call or not.

Answer (score 0):

Try to declare your method by arrow function :

```js
onRegisterPress = () => {
    //your code
}
```

And remove :

```js
this.onRegisterPress = this.onRegisterPress.bind(this);
```

And keep other code as it is. May this will help you.

Comment: thankyou for help before, but nothing change , still same .@.@

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it is the right answer.Since you mentioned in the comment that you are not receiving the function as props.

I find only reason as you are directly routing to the

`Register : { screen : RegisterComponent }` route

You need to route to

`RegisterCont : {screen : RegisterContainer }`

From here you are passing the `onRegisterPress` prop.
Please check for this.

Comment: From the RegisterCont route you are calling the RegisterComponent.In this case the prop onRegisterPress should pass to the component.If you direcly call RegisterComponent from Register route.You will get null.I have faced this issue before.

Comment: i know what you want to tell bro, but can u more detail wnat need t ochange ?

Comment: Why are there two routes Register and RegisterCont?.Since you are calling RegisterComponent which is in the route Regiter, inside the RegisterCont.Why not have only one route and your function will be called.Try removing the Register:{screen:RegisterComponent} from the RootNavigation file.

Comment: as you know i declare Register cont and Register. Register is link to register from login form if you dont have an account and form register cont is function to create data

Comment: So add the onRegisterPress code inside the login page too.

Comment: i cant add onRegisterPress in login because it different page. RegisterCont is just a function when we submit the form, login container is a function when we want to dashboard. from login page i create Button Register as Register it link to Register form, register form have button Submiit/Register if validate succes and it will call a function RegisterCont

Comment: Try regrouping your logic in the code.The prop name will be OnRegisterPress but the code will be related to the login page.

Comment: First : in Login page i call a screen Register that link to register from after i clock button register in login page, and it link to Register Component, register component has button Submit/Register it link to Register Container .

Comment: It would be nice if you can provide an expo link in minimal way so others can help.

Comment: do you have skype or email ? almot a hour i cant find the solution, i dont know where is the mistake that i did. i never did this before